# Bluetooth Programming in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, bluetooth

Surprisingly, there are hardly any extensive resources on the Internet regarding Bluetooth programming for Windows Phone. The [sample on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj207007(v=vs.105).aspx) 
just shows you how to search for paired devices, and that's pretty much where all the online guides terminate.

I need some kind of tutorial or resource which explains the ins and outs of actually transferring and receiving data from other devices via Bluetooth. In specific, I want to establish communication between an rfduino and a Windows Phone but really any generalized guide will suffice as long as it clearly explains the various classes involved (PeerInformation, PeerFinder, StreamSocket) and the protocol used.

So far all I've come across is an outdated toolkit called [32Feet](http://32feet.codeplex.com/). It has accompanying video tutorials but they're manually handling threading; I'm guessing this was before C# introduced `async` and `await`.

Is there a modern toolkit/resource out there for Windows PHone Bluetooth programming?